# Comparing signals recorded using diffrent methods

Tags: speech-processing, speech

Suppose we have two signals( focus to audio) recorded with different methods,
or more simply, suppose we have two audio signals recorded with different microphone, and  we want to confirm that these signals are of the same audio.

What are the available alogorithms or libraries that make this possible?

Comment: Take a look at cross correlation

Comment: If we are comparing the actual audio(digital) to the recorded audio. I have some music file in my computer and I record it using a microphone while playing, and I want to compare these two.
(Though focus here is to audio,it's not limited to audio, suppose I take a photo of some imagee in my computer screen with a camera, and I want to compare it to the original image)

Comment: Image processing is **very** different from audio processing.

Answer (score 2):

Different flavors of cross correlation are probably the best choice here. It really depends on how exactly the recordings are different. Two microphones side by side behave very differently than two microphones in different spots in the room. Your best method will depend on a clear understanding of what your application needs to cover and what doesn't.

Comment: If we are comparing the actual audio(digital) to the recorded audio. I have some music file in my computer and I record it using a microphone while playing, and I want to compare these two.
(Though focus here is to audio,it's not limited to audio, suppose I take a photo of some imagee in my computer screen with a camera, and I want to compare it to the original image)